# c# how to get selectedindex and do a sql query

Tags: c#, mysql, selectedindex

I am trying to get the selectedindex of listbox 1 and 2 and update my databasetable based on the values selected in the two listboxes, but can't find a way to get the selectedindexes into my sql statement. Any suggestions?

```
     private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        String cs = "Database=something;User=-;Password=-";
        MySqlConnection dbconn = new MySqlConnection(cs);
        dbconn.Open();

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(
            "select * from reservasjon WHERE Rom_nr IS NULL ", dbconn);
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        this.listBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        this.listBox1.DisplayMember = "Rnr";
      }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String cs = "Database=something;User=-;Password=-";
        MySqlConnection dbconn = new MySqlConnection(cs);
        dbconn.Open();
        DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter2 = new MySqlDataAdapter(
           "select * from rom WHERE etasje = '1' AND opptatt='1'", dbconn);
        adapter2.Fill(ds2);
        this.listBox2.DataSource = ds2.Tables[0];
        this.listBox2.DisplayMember = "Rom_nr";
    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string value1 = listBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString();
    }

    private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string value2 = listBox2.SelectedIndex.ToString();
    }



    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string value1 = listBox2.Text;
        string value2 = listBox1.Text;

        MySqlDataReader dr = null;

        try
        {
            String cs = "Database=something;User=-;Password=-";
            string selectStatement = "UPDATE reservasjon SET Rom_nr='102' WHERE Rnr='2';";
            System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
            MySqlConnection dbconn = new MySqlConnection(cs);
            dbconn.Open();
            MySqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            sqlDa.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(selectStatement, dbconn);
            MySqlCommandBuilder cb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(sqlDa);
            sqlDa.Fill(dt);
            dt.Rows[0]["Rnr"] = "";
            sqlDa.UpdateCommand = cb.GetUpdateCommand();
            sqlDa.Update(dt);
        }

        catch (Exception s)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you want to use the value of the SelectedIndex in your update query then you should read and use them where you create and run your query. You don't explain how these values should be used. By the way an UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE query should be executed using an MySqlCommand and the ExecuteNonQuery method.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you mean and are trying to accomplish. Selected index is simply a number pointing to the position of the selected index. If that's fine then use that in the query by grabbing it in the class in which you are using it or declare value1 globally. If you want the value of the item that is selected then you'll use the selected index to grab the item at that position in the array. Use a string.format builder to dynamically create your select query with variables.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick :

```
   private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string value1 = listBox2.Text;
        string value2 = listBox1.Text;

        MySqlDataReader dr = null;

        try
        {
            String cs = "Database=something;User=-;Password=-";
            string selectStatement = "UPDATE reservasjon SET Rom_nr='"+value2+"' WHERE Rnr='"value1+"';";
            System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
            MySqlConnection dbconn = new MySqlConnection(cs);
            dbconn.Open();
            MySqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            sqlDa.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(selectStatement, dbconn);
            MySqlCommandBuilder cb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(sqlDa);
            sqlDa.Fill(dt);
            dt.Rows[0]["Rnr"] = "";
            sqlDa.UpdateCommand = cb.GetUpdateCommand();
            sqlDa.Update(dt);
        }

        catch (Exception s)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just a comment, not sure this is really the entire answer to what they were asking, simply just how to drop a value into the string. Either way traditionally what you put is seen as somewhat bad practice and unmanageable, you should use string.Format("UPDATE whatever set value={0} where value={1}", value1, value2);

Answer (score 0):

That's cause your variable `value1` and `value2` is not available outside the event handler method since you made them local. Declare them globally or just use the `listBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString()` directly in your SQL query